# Why GNU Global doesn't index Pascal files of a project?

Tags: linux, parsing, pascal, pygments, gnu-global

I'm trying to index the Pascal files of a project, on Linux (modern Ubuntu).

I've followed the instructions, but I'm very confused because of several factors.

The procedure I've applied is:

```bash
$ apt install global exuberant-ctags
$ python3 -m pip install pygments

$ gtags --version
gtags (GNU GLOBAL) 6.6.4
```

Now, things start to get confusing, because first, there is no gtag.conf anywhere in the system.

There is a `/usr/share/doc/global/examples/gtags.conf.gz`, which says, at the top:

```
Basically, GLOBAL doesn't need this configuration file ('gtags.conf'),
because it has default values in itself. [...]
```

I ignore this comment, and run:

```bash
gzip -dc /usr/share/doc/global/examples/gtags.conf.gz > /tmp/gtags.conf

export GTAGSCONF=/tmp/gtags.conf
export GTAGSLABEL=pygments

gtags -v
```

I can see from the output:

```
[Sat Aug 13 13:57:58 CEST 2022] Gtags started.
 Using configuration file '/tmp/gtags.conf'.
 Using configuration label 'pygments'.
 Using plug-in parser.
[Sat Aug 13 13:57:58 CEST 2022] Creating 'GTAGS' and 'GRTAGS'.
 [1] extracting tags of FILE1.ASM
 [2] extracting tags of FILE2.ASM
[Sat Aug 13 13:57:58 CEST 2022] Done.
```

That no PAS files are included.

I try to follow the instructions from the [official tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html):

```bash
find . -name '*.PAS' > /tmp/list
gtags -vf /tmp/list
```

And the output doesn't include any file, essentially:

```
[Sat Aug 13 14:01:44 CEST 2022] Gtags started.
 Using configuration file '/tmp/gtags.conf'.
 Using configuration label 'pygments'.
 Using '/tmp/list' as a file list.
 Using plug-in parser.
[Sat Aug 13 14:01:44 CEST 2022] Creating 'GTAGS' and 'GRTAGS'.
[Sat Aug 13 14:01:44 CEST 2022] Done.
```

Now, I try to rename the `PAS` files to `pas` (or add `.PAS` to the `gtags.conf` file). It seems to get better:

```bash
$ gtags -v
[Sat Aug 13 14:04:57 CEST 2022] Gtags started.
 Using configuration file '/tmp/gtags.conf'.
 Using configuration label 'pygments'.
 Using plug-in parser.
[Sat Aug 13 14:04:57 CEST 2022] Creating 'GTAGS' and 'GRTAGS'.
 [1] extracting tags of FILE1.ASM
 [2] extracting tags of FILE2.pas
 [... all relevant files ...]
[Sat Aug 13 14:04:58 CEST 2022] Done.
```

But gtags seems no to index anything relevant, since this:

```bash
$ gtags -vf FILE2.pas
```

results in a big list of lines marked as `not found. ignored.`

What confuses me is that it seems that Global is not able to parse Pascal files for some reason, but on the other hand, I don't get any error (which I suppose is relate to Pygments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "`gtags`" command generates the index.
`gtags -vf relevant.lst` expects a list of files inside relevant.lst.

To query contents of a file, you must use "`global`" command.
E. g. `global -c function_na` should give you completed `function_name` as result (provided there is such function in your code)